# what tomcat native library should I be using in production?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I compile my spring mvc app, I get this in the output:

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;......
```

What exactly should I use in production that this is referring to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Tomcat-native](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) is a version of Tomcat that uses the highly optimized Apache Portable Runtime (APR), the same framework that powers the Apache HTTP server.

Comment: ok, so what steps must i take to fix the problem as it says XXX was not found on path..

Answer (score 6):

I found a [post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/85960/Tomcat/Tomcat-Native-library-not-found) out there:

> You can safely ignore this message if you want. Basically it is telling you that an optional shared library (dll on Windows) is not found. The APR is the Apache Portable Runtime. This is a native (non-java) library that can improve the performance of Tomcat in certain situations.
>   On both Windows and Unix/Linux you will need a C compiler to build this library.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this talk , http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Tuning-Tomcat-Mark-Thomas , where one of the Tomcat developers discuss how to tune Tomcat - including which of the connectors (Like NIO or APr) to consider. The message you get about APR is referring to [Tomcat Native](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi)

Answer (score 3):

My case: Seeing the same INFO message.

Centos 6.2 x86_64 Tomcat 8.0.14

This fixed the problem for me:

yum install tomcat-native

Answer (score 2):

To get `APR` working on a **Windows server**:

- install the [APR native libs](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi) into the Tomcat `bin` directory (for
  `64 bit` use the `tcnative` files in the `x64` subfolder)
- add the Tomcat `bin` folder to the Windows `%path%` (this adds `openssl` to your path)

**Additional Notes:**

You cannot use a Java `keystore` with the `APR` connector as it expects certificates in the normal Apache format. To convert a `pfx` certificate I used:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in domain.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out domain.cer
openssl pkcs12 -in domain.pfx -nocerts -nodes  -out domain.key
openssl pkcs12 -in domain.pfx -out domain-ca.crt -nodes -nokeys -cacerts
```

You will then be able to uncomment / enable the example `SSL` using the `APR` connector in Tomcat's `server.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I was very new to Tomcat and faced the same problem; I think it was because I didn't stop the server properly.

In Eclipse, on the Server tab, right-click Tomcat and click "Clean". Restart the server. It worked for me.