# Minor glitch in running Struts2 helloWorld tutorials [TOMCAT]

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I'm trying to run the helloworld tutorials for struts2 in  my eclipse indigo. When i start my tomcat server, I get the following message in the console window. The highlighted bit is the one that i'm not able to understand.

```
Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init  

**INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;**

**Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsExample1' did not find a matching property.**

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 735 ms

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 2586 ms
```

And when I to open tomcat on my browser by typing `http://localhost:8080`, the error message **HTTP Status 404 - /** is Displayed. I am unable to understand the root cause of the problem. I use windows7 64bit. Is it because that my system and user variables are not properly defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tomcat is already running .

See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10972634/1085285

But you are not accessing your application. In order to run your application. You have to give url to something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp  where MyWebApp is the name you have given to your project
```

See this question and answer for the info message you are getting 
[what tomcat native library should I be using in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231163/1085285)