# Jsp+Java application execution not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I'm sorry of being so general, but I have a problem with my application execution and I have no idea of what it could be.
It's made by Jsp and Java parts, and developed with Eclipse. It uses a Postgresql database and an Apache Tomcat server.

When I click on **Run As -> Run On Server**, the program stops immediately. This is what Eclipse shows:

[image]

And this is what the console prints:

> 17-lug-2012 14.53.31 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path:
>
> C:\Programmi\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Programmi/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Programmi/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Programmi/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Programmi\CollabNet\Subversion
>   Client;C:\Programmi\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
>   c:\Programmi\Microsoft
>   SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Programmi\Intel\DMIX;C:\Programmi\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Programmi\MATLAB\R2010a\runtime\win32;C:\Programmi\MATLAB\R2010a\bin;C:\Programmi\File
>   comuni\Autodesk
>   Shared\;C:\Programmi\R-Language\R-2.13.1\bin\;C:\Programmi\R-Language\R-2.13.1\bin\;C:\Programmi\OpenVPN\bin\;
>   C:\Programmi\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\ 17-lug-2012 14.53.31
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>
> AVVERTENZA:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BioTesiWeb' did not
>   find a matching property. 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
>
> INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
>
> INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>
> INFO: Initialization processed in 460 ms 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>
> INFO: Starting service Catalina 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>
> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.6 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
>
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
>
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] 17-lug-2012 14.53.32
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>
> INFO: Server startup in 401
>   ms

Have you any idea of why the execution of the program fails?
Are there some libraries missing?
Have I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details...

For now just Check ur Servlet mapping in web.xml ? And also the servlet is named correctly...

Take a look at the below links for the error your getting

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231163/what-tomcat-native-library-should-i-be-using-in-production

[APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found on the java.library.path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278047/apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-on-the-java-library-path)

Comment: I dont understand why a vote down was done...the server seems to have started seamlessly ...so the only mistake could be the application was not deployed at all...or a wrong mapping was done..